# FETCH DATA BASED ON PARTICULAR STRING

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I need to fetch records based on particular type(FFRT-TR= ) and then replace it. For example below are the record types

20017546 FFRT-TR= 3456

TT:SX 2398 FFRT-TR=6532

I need to fetch records which contains FFRT-TR= and then replace the whole the of FFRT-TR=3456 Required Output based on the above examples: 20017546(for 1st example) 2398(for 2nd example)

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Specify your RDBMS.

Comment: So, all numerics before the literal string `FFRT-TR=`? Then replace the entire column string with *only* those numeric values?

Comment: @JacobH yes, need to get all the numerals before FFRT-TR= and then replace FFRT-TR=%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? Oracle-ish (you didn't specify the database you use), but - hopefully - you'll be able to rewrite it if necessary.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '20017546 FFRT-TR= 3456' from dual union
  3     select 'TT:SX 2398 FFRT-TR=6532' from dual
  4    )
  5  select
  6    col,
  7    replace(regexp_substr(col, '\d+ FFRT-TR='), 'FFRT-TR=', '') result
  8  from test;

COL                     RESULT
----------------------- ----------------------------------------------------
20017546 FFRT-TR= 3456  20017546
TT:SX 2398 FFRT-TR=6532 2398

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help on this. It helps !!

Comment: CASE? Well, you have to *remove* everything you don't need, so - even if you could do it, it would be more complicated than this.